# Static code analysis module in Perl

Tags: perl, static-code-analysis, perl-critic

Is there any static code analysis module in Perl except B::Lint and Perl::Critic? How effective is Module::Checkstyle?

Comment: Module::Checkstyle hasn't been updated since 2006.  A lot has changed in the modernization of Perl coding practices since 2006.  Perl::Critic is actively maintained, and seems to be a better basket for your eggs.  There is Test::Kwalitee, but it just looks to see that a dozen talking points are satisfied -- nowhere near as thorough or flexible as Perl::Critic.  Don't forget about the Devel:: namespace.  Lots of good stuff there: Devel::Cover, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=943316) on perlmonks.org asking if PPI can be used for static analysis. PPI is the power behind Perl::Critic, according to the [reviews](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/PPI) of this module. (I have not used it yet).

Then there is [perltidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PerlTidy).